# How do I resize a Windows Forms form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window-resize

I am making a Windows Forms application. I want the forms height to increase after a button is pressed. How do I do this?

Comment: Related: *[Change form size at runtime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064350)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`Height` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx). For instance:

```
this.Height = newHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just increase the form height value by a specified amount on the button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amountToIncrease = 10;
    this.Height += amountToIncrease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Size = new Size(175, 125);
```

or

```
this.ClientSize = new Size(175, 125);
```

From MSDN: The size of the client area of the form is the size of the form excluding the borders and the title bar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2(v=vs.80).aspx