# How to make the size of a Form go back to the original size after an event is trigged?

Tags: c#, winforms

1. I tried to change the values with `this.Height` and `this.Width`, but it didn't work after I clicked the button. Any idea why it's not working?
2. The PictureBox inside the Form worked with the same strategy though.

```
private void clear_ClickButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox5.Image = null;
    pictureBox5.Height = 500;
    pictureBox5.Width = 672;
    this.Width = 890;
    this.Height = 662;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    pictureBox7.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: If the Form is maximized (I assume you're trying to set it back to normal state. This: `this.MaximizeBox = false;` hides the Button), then just `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;`. Btw, don't do this: `pictureBox5.Image = null;` to remove an Image, dispose of it instead: `pictureBox5.Image?.Dispose();`. Unless the property is referencing an existing Bitmap object that you want to use again later.

Comment: Did you store the original size somewhere?

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for the enlightment, the `pictureBox5.Image?.Dispose()` its a very good solution. As for the `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;` didnt worked, neither the `this.Size = new Size(890; 662);`. @TaW, I did set the MinimumSize to (890; 662),  but didn`t work either when i reset it. I think that might have to do with any of the properties set in the Properties Window. (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732768066261483522/762508932140236840/unknown.png) (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732768066261483522/762509040328245299/unknown.png)

Answer (score 0):

First at all, I assume you speak about WinForm.

```
Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(890, 662);
```

For more info [How to: Resize Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-resize-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and [Change form size at runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064350/change-form-size-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)