# Change width of a Windows Forms form at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change width of a Windows Forms form at runtime. I am also executing SuspendLayout and resumelayout method, but it doesn't work.

```
  System.Windows.Forms.Control form = this.currentForm;
  form.SuspendLayout();
  form.Width = form.Width + 100;
  form.ResumeLayout();
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: "but it doesn't work." - please explain.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984427(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: In which context do you use the above code? Please show more. What is `this` and what is `this.currentForm`?

Comment: Related: *[How do I resize a Windows Forms form in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682506)*

Answer (score 3):

Set the size of form like this

```
Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
```

or

```
Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, Form1.Size.Height);
```

Once the Size has been defined, you can change Form size like this

```
Form1.Width += 200;
```

[MSDN - Resizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984427%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
form.Size = new Size(form.Size.Width + 100, form.Size.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, replace "Form1" with your form name. It's this easy:

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Width += 100;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's different than `form.Width = form.Width + 100;` ? .. and how if it's not activeform ?