# C# and Windows Forms application form size

Tags: c#, size

I was working on a Windows Forms application today that was functioning correctly. When I changed the font size of some buttons, textboxes and labels the form zoomed in and now it is far too big on runtime, and I can't figure out how to change the size back.

[image: Form Designer]

The first image shows the form designer and the second shows the form running hard to show as it is bigger than the screen size.

[image: Form when running]

Comment: Screenshots and/or code?

Comment: The form will auto-scale when you change its Font property.  Just edit the Size property in the Properties window.  Or the Font property.  Or restore from source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing a form, keep in mind that the screen DPI, user font settings (zoom, etc), and other factors can cause a form to change size. It's a good idea to make your forms handle such changes gracefully.

To keep things visible, use layout controls. In the Toolbox, they are under "Containers". Based on your screenshot, I would assume a `TableLayoutPanel` would work best. You might want to use a `SplitContainer` that has its `Orientation` set to Vertical and `IsSplitterFixed` set to True. You may need to nest some things depending on how exactly you want it laid out.

Once you have done that, you can use the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of the controls to position and size them within the containers.

When all of this is put together, you can resize a form, and the controls will stay in place, move around, change size, and/or do anything else that they and their containers are set to do. No additional coding to control size would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the size value or ClientSize of the form,

```
this.Size = new Size(200, 200);
```

or

```
this.ClientSize = new Size(200, 200);
```

Or you can view the form in Visual Studio and click on the side of it and play with its size.

See: *[How do I resize a Windows Forms form in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682506/how-to-resize-a-windows-form-in-c)*

Comment: thank you, both of these reduce the form size however now most of my controls are off screen. Not sure what is wrong as I thought I had only changed some font sizes

Comment: @Besty You should really use the Form Designer, you'll see what's up

Comment: thanks for your help I cant see anything wrong in the designer it is almost like the form is zooming in as it opens

Comment: @Besty could you post a screenshot of the form designer and the "zoomed" form ? I'm curious to see.